# Para qué sirve 'isKeyPressed' JAVA

Tags: java, entrada, teclado

estoy comenzando a usar Slick2d en Java. Quiero usar el método de entrada 'isKeyPressed', aunque no termino de entender cómo funciona. ¿Alguien me puede dar una breve explicación? Gracias.

```
private Input entrada;
private Image imagen;

private boolean ImagenPulsada;

public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    if (entrada.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_SPACE)) imagenPulsada = true;

    if (imagenPulsada) imagen.draw(100,100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método IsKeyPressed de la classe Input, te dice (true o false) si, en el momento de llamar a dicho método, la tecla que se indica (como parámetro de entrada) está presionada.

En tu caso la barra espaciadora.

La classe Input sirve para poder monitoritzar la actividad en  dispositivos como teclados o mouses.